# Amazon Order Fulfillment with Multiple Packages for one Order _POST_ORDER_FULFILLMENT_DATA_

Tags: amazon-mws

I have been dealing with a problem that pops up once a day.  An order with multiple packages (fulfillmentdata,item).  This is an order where the person may have ordered two different items and they were sent by the merchant in two different packages with different tracking numbers.  Tends to be uncommon on amazon but very common in other systems.

I have tried multiple versions of the XML to try and make this work but to no success.
My first attempt:

```
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
<Header>
<DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
<MerchantIdentifier>XXXXXXXX</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>
<MessageType>OrderFulfillment</MessageType>
<Message>
  <MessageID>1</MessageID>
   <OrderFulfillment>
    <MerchantOrderID>55XXXX</MerchantOrderID>
    <FulfillmentDate>2018-10-01T17:XX:XX-00:00</FulfillmentDate>
    <FulfillmentData>
     <CarrierCode>USPS</CarrierCode>
     <ShippingMethod>First Class Parcel</ShippingMethod>
     <ShipperTrackingNumber>940011590109XXXXXX</ShipperTrackingNumber>
    </FulfillmentData>
    <FulfillmentData>
     <CarrierCode>USPS</CarrierCode>
     <ShippingMethod>First Class Parcel</ShippingMethod>
     <ShipperTrackingNumber>940011590109XXXXX</ShipperTrackingNumber>
    </FulfillmentData>
    <Item>
      <AmazonOrderItemCode>354178450XXXX</AmazonOrderItemCode>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <AmazonOrderItemCode>014909917XXXX</AmazonOrderItemCode>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    </Item>
   </OrderFulfillment>
 </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Next I tried to split it up into two different messages

```
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
<Header>
 <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
 <MerchantIdentifier>XXXXXXXX</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>
<MessageType>OrderFulfillment</MessageType>
<Message>
<MessageID>1</MessageID>
 <OrderFulfillment>
  <MerchantOrderID>554XXX</MerchantOrderID>
  <FulfillmentDate>2018-10-01T17:XX:XX-00:00</FulfillmentDate>
  <FulfillmentData>
    <CarrierCode>USPS</CarrierCode>
    <ShippingMethod>First Class Parcel</ShippingMethod>
    <ShipperTrackingNumber>94001159010920XX</ShipperTrackingNumber>
  </FulfillmentData>
  <Item>
    <AmazonOrderItemCode>0149099174XXXX</AmazonOrderItemCode>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
  </Item>
 </OrderFulfillment>
</Message>
<Message>
<MessageID>2</MessageID>
 <OrderFulfillment>
  <MerchantOrderID>554XXX</MerchantOrderID>
  <FulfillmentDate>2018-10-01T17:XX:XX-00:00</FulfillmentDate>
  <FulfillmentData>
    <CarrierCode>USPS</CarrierCode>
    <ShippingMethod>First Class Parcel</ShippingMethod>
    <ShipperTrackingNumber>9400115901092029XXX</ShipperTrackingNumber>
  </FulfillmentData>
  <Item>
    <AmazonOrderItemCode>3541784506XXXX</AmazonOrderItemCode>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
  </Item>
 </OrderFulfillment>
</Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

With the second message I received the following error (for both message 1 and 2):

```
<MessageID>2</MessageID>
    <ResultCode>Error</ResultCode>
    <ResultMessageCode>18028</ResultMessageCode>
    <ResultDescription>The data you submitted is incomplete or invalid. For help fixing this, see http://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/help/30721</ResultDescription>
```

Comment: I have the same question.  Dan, have you figured out, how to make this?

Comment: @arudoy Unfortunately the only answer I found was to use the file based version.

Comment: @Dan Can you share a link to where I could read about the file based version?